# Duvida sobre KeyPress no Pygame

Tags: python, teclado, pygame

tenho uma duvida relacionada ao Pygame.

Estou começando a mexer e encontrei um problema aqui. Quando aperto o botão A(esquerda) faço com que a imagem ande para a esquerda, até ai tudo ok.
Porém se mantenho a tecla pressionada ele não repete o movimento. Tenho que despressionar e pressionar novamente a tecla.

Outra coisa, como coloquei um sleep de 0.07, se eu pressionar a tecla X vezes nesse intervalo de tempo, ele repetirá esse movimento X vezes, mesmo não estando com a tecla pressionada.

Link do GitHub: https://github.com/EmanoelFraguas/GitProject/tree/master/Python/Pok%C3%A9%20Engine

Imagino que deve ser um problema bem bobo, mas me perdoem. Apenas estou aprendendo e sou curioso com essas coias.
Até já aprendi a mexer no GitHub haha :d

Código da minha classe:

```
class Arcanine(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def moveLeft(self):
        for i in range(4):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                pygame.display.flip()
                screen.fill(0)
                screen.blit(mapa, mappos)
                arcapos[0] = arcapos[0] - 8
                screen.blit(arca1, arcapos)
                time.sleep(0.07)
            else:
                pygame.display.flip()
                screen.fill(0)
                screen.blit(mapa, mappos)
                arcapos[0] = arcapos[0] - 8
                screen.blit(arca2, arcapos)
                time.sleep(0.07)
```

Código da execução:

```
while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(mapa, mappos)
    screen.blit(arca2, arcapos) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                keys[0] = True
            elif event.key == K_s:
                keys[1] = True
            elif event.key == K_a:
                keys[2] = True
            elif event.key == K_d:
                keys[3] = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_w:
                keys[0] = False
            elif event.key == K_s:
                keys[1] = False
            elif event.key == K_a:
                keys[2] = False
            elif event.key == K_d:
                keys[3] = False

        if keys[0]:
            pass
        elif keys[1]:
            pass
        if keys[2]:
            arca.moveLeft()
        elif keys[3]:
            pass    

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você pegar o `KEYDOWN` como está fazendo, ele vai repetir sim, mas não de forma uniforme.

O ideal aí é usar o pygame.key.get_pressed()

Mas antes disso - você percebe que tem algum codigo repetido no seu move_left? E que quando tiver as outras funçoes que está fazendo, esse código vai se repetir em mais um monte de lugares?

Então - em particular, as chamadas
`pygame.display.flip()` e  `time.sleep` devem ser feitas APENAS uma vez no programa, perto do fim do seu loop principal (no caso o "whle True"). As funçoes podem atua.izar variávei, desenahr coisa sno buffer da tela, etc... mas deixe apenas uma chamada para atualizar a tela, e uma chamada de pausa para a próxima execução do loop, que deve acontecer toda vez, não só de vez em quando.

Se você fizer só isso, já deve melhorar bastante. (Em particular tem um outro problema: você faz a pausa primeiro, chamando o sleep, e *depois* atualiza a tela: ou seja, o jogador fica olhando a tela antiga, e depois do frame é que a tela é atualizada -  o certo é atualizar a tela, e fazer a pausa. É melhor também chamar `pygame.time.delay` em vez de `time.sleep`, só pra manter a consistência, mas isso não vai fazer diferença no seu jogo.

Faça essas alterações, já deve melhorar. Depois veja a documentação do `pygame.key.get_pressed` como mencionei: uma única chamada retorna quais teclas estão pressionadas *naquele momento*: você só copia alguns valores da lista retornada para a sua lista `keys`: ela já retorna "True" ou "False" dependendo da tecla estar pressionada.

```
class Arcanine(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.moving_counter = 0
        self.moving_method = None

    def moving_left(self):
        arcapos[0] = arcapos[0] - 8
        if self.moving_counter % 2 == 0:
            screen.blit(arca1, arcapos)
        else:
        screen.blit(arca2, arcapos)

    def moving(self):
        if not self.moving_counter:
            return
        screen.fill(0)
        screen.blit(mapa, mappos)
        self.moving_method()
        self.moving_counter -= 1

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.moving_method = self.moving_left
        self.moving_counter = 4


while True:
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(mapa, mappos)
    screen.blit(arca2, arcapos) 

    pygame.event.pump()
    keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()

    keys[0] = keys[K_w]
    keys[1] = keys[K_s]
    keys[2] = keys[K_a]
    keys[3] = keys[K_d]

    if keys[0]:
        pass
    elif keys[1]:
        pass
    if keys[2]:
        arca.moveLeft()
    elif keys[3]:
        pass    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

    pygame.time.delay(70)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Esse código, além das sugestões acima, integra a pausa e movimento contínuo no "loop principal", apenas usando variáveis de estado na sua classe.  Eu não tinha reparado que você fazia atualizações separadas dentro do método. COm essa integração ao loop principal para a animaão da classe, o restante do jogo continua funcionando enquanto o "moveLeft" está ativo.

Comment: Sobre o `time.sleep` é porque eu faço uma animação, que a cada 0.07 movo 8 pixels para o lado as coordenadas da imagem, e a cada uma mudo a `.png`para mexer as pernas do personagem dando movimento.
Sobre o `get_pressed`vou dar uma procurada aqui.
Dei uma atualizada no arquivo pelo Git.

Comment: Acabei de conseguir aqui com o `get_pressed()`:
`press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
 if press[119] == 1:
  arca.moveUp()`
quando deixo pressionado desta forma ele continua movendo.

Comment: é, mas não use "119", use as mesmas constantes que usa ao verificar o evento: K_w, e etc... -- como alguém, ou você mesmo, vendo seu código daqui duas semanas, vai saber que o "119" é  correspondente à tecla "w"?

Answer (score 0):

Veja este exemplo de um jogo 'space invader', a abordagem que ele usa é interessante. Basicamente quando o jogador aperta o botão, ele atribui um flag true, e desabilita esse flag no keyup (despressionar). Ou seja, no código abaixo, ship.moving_right será True enquanto o jogador estiver pressionando a tecla seta para direita.

Do código fonte do livro Python Crash Course:

https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_12/game_functions.py

```
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
```